# Get UITableViewRowAction to bounce on tap

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I want to add feedback for a table cell with a row action. When the user clicks the cell the row action will bounce open a bit. I've seen this somewhere before, it shows the user theres a menu.

I don't see anything in the docs that would give me that control.

Answer (score 0):

```
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

                cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.origin.x)!-15, y: (cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: cell!.bounds.size.width, height: cell!.bounds.size.height)

            }) { (finished) in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

                    cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (cell?.frame.origin.x)!+15, y: (cell?.frame.origin.y)!, width: cell!.bounds.size.width, height: cell!.bounds.size.height)

                })
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            }
```